# To show data in to read a File txt in ionic, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Sorry for my bad English. I'm new in phonegap and I'm trying to read a file and show the data, but I've a problem in the FileSystem. 
The window.requestFileSystem not calls to the "fail" method.
My full code is:

```
$scope.fail=function(){
    alert("fallo");
}
$scope.gotFS = function(fileSystem) {
  fileSystem.root.getFile('QReminderStyle/tema.txt', 0, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

$scope.gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

$scope.abrirArchivo=function(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }
  )}

$scope.gotFile=function(file){
    readAsText(file);
}

  $scope.readAsText = function(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        alert("Read as text");
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);        
  }
```

I can't to do a log because I'm running in the real device.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.fail` instead of just `fail`?

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for your comment, I modify with the $scope.fail and the error is the same.

Comment: So, you are getting an error? ... which is the error?

Comment: not continue the execution and no calls to the fail method.

Comment: I resolved with $scope. in all the functions. Thanks for your help.-